# Multiply two fields together in django orm

Tags: python, mysql, django

How would I do the following query (in pseudocode):

```
CueCompletion.objects.filter(
    user_id=profile_user.pk, status_action_taken_on__gte=day_ago
).sum('amount' * 'opportunities')
```

Basically, I want to get the sum of the amount * opportunities for the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to achieve it is to use a Queryset method called [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

It returns a particular queryset (a ValuesListQuerySet), and then you can make some further computations on it.

You can do this:

`vqs = CueCompletion.objects.filter(
    user_id=profile_user.pk, status_action_taken_on__gte=day_ago
).values_list('amount','opportunities')`

and then you will have something like `vqs = [(50, 2), (100, 4), (25, 2), ...]`, i.e. a "list" of *n* tuples, each with the value of *amount* and *opportunities* field.

(actually `vqs` it's not a list, it's a ValuesListQuerySet, but doesn't matter for our next move).

---

Our next move (a.k.a. the further computations) is:

`total = sum(t[0] * t[1] for t in vqs)`

where we are using the built-it [sum()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum) function on a generator containing all our (*amount* * *opportunities*) results.

(why using a generator instead of a list comprehension? check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189840/4594377)!)

Comment: You deserve a medal for this solution.

Answer (score 5):

You could also add an annotation to the queryset while using the `F` object. This way you are doing all the calculations in the database which could be faster than pulling all the values into a list and doing a list comprehension using python memory.

```
CueCompletion.objects.filter(
user_id=profile_user.pk, status_action_taken_on__gte=day_ago
).annotate(total=F('amount') * F('opportunities'))
```

Now you can access this value by the `total` variable.

Comment: this is awesome, was looking for this solution for over an hour

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: from django.db.models import F